# Two forms of Dedekinds law for groups and their equivalence

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group with subgroups $A,B$ and $C$. Then I call:

i) Weak Dedekind law.

If $G = AB$ and $A \le C \le G$, then $C = A(B\cap C)$.

ii) Dedekind law.

If $A \le B$, then $AC \cap B = A(C \cap B)$.

I want to know if i) and ii) are equivalant. Of course ii) implies i) for if $G = AB$ and $A \le C \le G$, then by applying ii) for $A \le C$ with $B$ we have
$$
 C = AB \cap C = A(B \cap C)
$$
but I am not sure about the other direction?

Comment: Since they both true (in all groups, not just finite groups), then I guess they are equivalent!

Comment: Okay, then let me be more specific. I am asking for a proof of their equivalence. I am note quite sure what you mean, but for example the formula $|AB| = |A||B|/|A\cap B|$ also holds in all finite groups, hence I would not say it to be equivalent to any other statement (like for example Dedekinds law) which holds in all finite groups...

Comment: If two (independent) statements are true, then they are equivalent by vacuous truth. So the Dedekind laws are also equivalent to moon revolves around earth!

Comment: Also any two false statements are equivalent. The idea of two statements being equivalent can only be meaningfully applied when they are sometimes true and sometimes false.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the interesting remarks! So my question is pointless? But I have shown a way to derive i) from ii) directly, so is it possible to derive ii) from i) directly, or is this question meaningless? And what if we switch to more general algebraic structures, like semigroups, then are they still equivalent, or is this question still meaningless, or just meaningless in the context of groups?